# Spark - IllegalArgumentException in KMeans.train

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running into an exception while inside `KMeans.train()` like below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:212)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.fastSquaredDistance(MLUtils.scala:487)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.fastSquaredDistance(KMeans.scala:589)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$runAlgorithm$3.apply(KMeans.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$runAlgorithm$3.apply(KMeans.scala:301)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.runAlgorithm(KMeans.scala:301)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.run(KMeans.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.run(KMeans.scala:209)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.train(KMeans.scala:530)
```

This doesn't give me any clue on where to start debugging.
I found an old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678366/spark-ml-kmeans-give-org-apache-spark-sparkexception-failed-to-execute-user-d) but that issue was in `KMeans.predict()` whereas this is happening in the training phase itself.

Comment: What is your input and code?

Comment: I'm considering closing this question as a dupe for the one you have linked, yet I'm not very sure. Would you care please reviewing your question considering these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: @eliasah: may well be a duplicate - from [Spark ML Github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.scala) the two requirements for `fastSquaredDistance` are 1) vectors are of the same size and 2) both norms are positive.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreDupriez ! I'm suspecting that but I was giving a chance to the OP in case it's not an exact dupe so I don't close this single-handedly and after the screaming starts :)

Comment: @eliasah, AlexandreDupriez The link I posted only mentions about the dimensions of the vectors being same. In my case, all vectors have same dimensions. I crossed checked this before posting. I am not aware of the norm though, how do I ensure that it is +ve ?

Comment: @Shaido My input has about 100K vectors and corresponding label for each vector. It works for certain set of inputs but one or two large inputs, it fails with this exception

Comment: The issue is that you say that but your error says dimensions are different. Can you create an MVCE ?

Comment: @eliasah I will cross check the dimensions one more time.

Comment: @eliasah I did a binary search on my dataset's rows using limit() and except() and narrowed down to exact feature vector thats causing this crash. I found out that one of vectors had "NaN" in a column and this must be why its causing the crash. Thanks for all the help and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at the source code and it will become clear:

1. Your vectors have to have the same size.
2. The norms of both vectors should be non-negative.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/17af727e38c3faaeab5b91a8cdab5f2181cf3fc4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.scala#L500

`private[mllib] def fastSquaredDistance(
    v1: Vector,
    norm1: Double,
    v2: Vector,
    norm2: Double,
    precision: Double = 1e-6): Double = {
  val n = v1.size
  require(v2.size == n)
  require(norm1 >= 0.0 && norm2 >= 0.0)
...`

Comment: My input satisfies #1. How do I check if the norm is +ve or -ve ? How do I handle the case where it is -ve ? Pls. help

Answer (score 0):

The most possible cause of this error is that the input values in the vector are of varying dimensions. We can be more certain on this reason if you can share the details of the inputs (vector inputs) being passed.

Please recheck that vectors being passed are of same dimensions.

Comment: Yes, the dimensions are same for all vectors. After I ran into the post (the link I posted), I added this checking within my program to ensure this is not the case. Others are suggesting that -ve norm could be the reason. How do I ensure that norm is +ve for give vectors and how do I handle this if it is -ve ?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your rows has null values, use: "dropna" or equivalent